# Как сделать отступ между картинкой и текстом?

Tags: html, css

Текст не сместился вправо, а просто остался под картинкой:

[image: описание]Я хотел бы в классе header_inner между картинкой и текстом сделать отступ, но justify-content: space-between; не работает. Вот написанный html код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf=8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Lato:ital,wght@0,300;0,700;0,900;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="webpaint.css">
        <title>We are Webpaint</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header__inner">

                    <div class="header__logo">
                        <div class="im1"><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logo"></div>
                    </div>
                

                    <nav class="nav">
                        <a class="nav__link" href="#">HOME</a>
                        <a class="nav__link" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
                        <a class="nav__link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                        <a class="nav__link" href="#">BLOG</a>
                        <a class="nav__link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    </nav>
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>

Часть кода CSS:
    .header__inner{
        width:100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

Comment: В вашем коде картинка и текст находятся в одной строке. Картинка прижата к левому краю окна, текст - к правому. А как вам нужно, чтобы было? Что значит "не работает"?

Comment: Согласен, у вас `justify-content: space-between;` работает.

Comment: Проверьте правильно ли подключены у вас `css стили`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

Должно работать, но у Вас даже flex не применился. Проверьте путь к файлу стилей. Возможно Вам стоит добавить еще `type`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webpaint.css">
```

А вообще, `css` файлы обычно лежат в папке `css`, поэтому:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/webpaint.css">
```

Проверить подключен ли стиль можно в chrome нажав `f12`, и посмотреть нет ли ошибок. А во вкладке `source` должен быть Ваш файл стилей. Например, у меня это

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.min.css">
```

и вот он на скрине подключен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А еще если в VS code Зажать `ctrl` и нажать на путь к файлу, то Вас должно перебросить в сам файл. Если этого не происходит, Вы неправильно его подключили.

Ну и последнее: Сохраните все файлы, а затем обновите страницу с Вашим сайтом, тогда стили должны примениться, если файл `css` подключен.

Comment: спасибо больное, @Konstantin_SH, когда нажал f12 в header_inner оказывается ничего не было. теперь исправил